# How to use php sessions in AndroidStudio

Tags: http, android-studio, session, android-volley

I'm working in an android application that connects with the server ,
and i'm not allowed to change the web services ,
the web service works with sessions ,
how do i make my android app save sessions like a browser when i send a post or a get and the servers works with sessions from my application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is using Http-client in apache library 
the request is sent this way :

```
        HttpGet post = new HttpGet(url);
        post.setHeader("User-Agent", "Android");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(post);
```

One way to save the sessions like php does :
is to use android sharedPreferences 
here is an example :
https://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/